# Cannot configure r-base on Linux: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to install and upgrade R on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). However, I get a mysterious error and am having trouble diagnosing it. The most similar error that I can find online is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855013/safely-cleanup-apt-get-after-a-failed-r-installation-from-an-added-repo).

The full error is at the bottom of the post. However, it appears the source of the problem is in the following lines.

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst: paperconf: not found
    dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

The entire output is as follows.

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  r-base-dev r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools
  r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix
  r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial
  r-cran-survival r-recommended
Suggested packages:
  r-doc-info | r-doc-pdf r-mathlib r-base-html
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster
  r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass
  r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart
  r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-recommended
0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/36.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 55.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Selecting previously unselected package r-base-core.
(Reading database ... 429546 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-base-core_3.2.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-base-core (3.2.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-base-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../r-base-dev_3.2.3-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-base-dev (3.2.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-boot.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-boot_1.3-17-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-boot (1.3-17-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-mass.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-mass_7.3-45-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-mass (7.3-45-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-class.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-class_7.3-14-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-class (7.3-14-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-cluster.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-cluster_2.0.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-cluster (2.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-codetools.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-codetools_0.2-14-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-codetools (0.2-14-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-foreign.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-foreign_0.8.66-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-foreign (0.8.66-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-kernsmooth.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-kernsmooth_2.23-15-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-kernsmooth (2.23-15-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-lattice.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-lattice_0.20-33-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-lattice (0.20-33-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-matrix.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-matrix_1.2-3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-matrix (1.2-3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-nlme.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-nlme_3.1.124-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-nlme (3.1.124-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-mgcv.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-mgcv_1.8-11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-mgcv (1.8-11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-nnet.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-nnet_7.3-12-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-nnet (7.3-12-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-survival.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-survival_2.38-3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-survival (2.38-3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-rpart.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-rpart_4.1-10-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-rpart (4.1-10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-spatial.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-spatial_7.3-11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-spatial (7.3-11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-recommended.
Preparing to unpack .../r-recommended_3.2.3-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-recommended (3.2.3-4) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for tex-common (6.04) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running mtxrun --generate. This may take some time... done.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up r-base-core (3.2.3-4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst: paperconf: not found
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-base-dev:
 r-base-dev depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-base-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-boot:
 r-cran-boot depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-2); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-boot depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-boot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-mass:
 r-cran-mass depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-mass depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing pNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
ackage r-cran-mass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-class:
 r-cran-class depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-class depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-class depends on r-cran-mass; however:
  Package r-cran-mass is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-class (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-cluster:
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-cluster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkgNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-codetools:
 r-cran-codetools depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-codetools depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-codetools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-foreign:
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-foreign depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-foreign (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-kernsmooth:
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-2); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-kernsmooth depends on r-cran-mass; however:
  Package r-cran-mass is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-kernsmooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-lattice:
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-lattice depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-lattice (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-matrix:
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-api-3; however:
  PNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
ackage r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-matrix depends on r-cran-lattice (>= 0.12-11.1); however:
  Package r-cran-lattice is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-matrix (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-nlme:
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-nlme depends on r-cran-lattice (>= 0.12-11.1); however:
  Package r-cran-lattice is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-nlme (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-mgcv:
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cranNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
-mgcv depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-cran-nlme; however:
  Package r-cran-nlme is not configured yet.
 r-cran-mgcv depends on r-cran-matrix; however:
  Package r-cran-matrix is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-mgcv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-nnet:
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-nnet depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-nnet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-survival:
 r-cran-survival depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-3); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-survival depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-survival (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-rpart:
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-2); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.
 r-cran-rpart depends on r-cran-survival; however:
  Package r-cran-survival is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package r-cran-rpart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-spatial:
 r-cran-spatial depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-spatial depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-spatial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-recommended:
 r-recommended depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-4); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-boot (>= 1.2.19); however:
  Package r-cran-boot is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-cluster (>= 1.9.6-2); however:
  Package r-cran-cluster is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-foreign (>= 0.7-2); however:
  Package r-cran-foreign is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-kernsmooth (>= 2.2.14); however:
  Package r-cran-kernsmooth is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-lattice (>= 0.10.11); however:
  Package r-cran-lattice is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-mgcv (>= 1.1.5); however:
  Package r-cran-mgcv is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-nlme (>= 3.1.52); however:
  Package r-cran-nlme is not configured yet.
 r-recommended depends on r-cran-rpart (>= 3.1.20); however:
  Package r-cran-rpart is No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
not c
dpkg: error processing package r-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r-base-core
 r-base-dev
 r-cran-boot
 r-cran-mass
 r-cran-class
 r-cran-cluster
 r-cran-codetools
 r-cran-foreign
 r-cran-kernsmooth
 r-cran-lattice
 r-cran-matrix
 r-cran-nlme
 r-cran-mgcv
 r-cran-nnet
 r-cran-survival
 r-cran-rpart
 r-cran-spatial
 r-recommended
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```